# I'm trying to get a button to go to next activity given conditions are true but it won't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the code that should let me go to next activity with 3 methods I made. The `checkEditText` method should take an `editText` parameter and change it to a string and then make sure it is not empty. The `checkTextLetters` should take the `editText` parameter and then make sure it contains only letters and/or spaces. Then the method `configureNextButton` should only run if the 2 previous methods are true:

```
private boolean checkEditText(EditText text){

    if(text.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    //try and print to screen "name is left blank//
    return false;
}
```

I would think this method would return `true` whenever I type `asdf` or something in the plain text:

```
private boolean checkTextLetters(EditText text){
    String line = text.getText().toString();

    //checks to make sure that the string contains only the characters a-z and A-Z and/or spaces
    boolean checkChars = line.matches("[a-zA-Z]");
    boolean checkSpaces = line.matches("\\s+");
    if(checkChars && checkSpaces){
        return true;
    }
    else if(checkChars){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method should just take the text from the plain text that I typed in and check to make sure it only contains letters and spaces:

```
private void configureNextButton(boolean textCheck, boolean checkIfLetters){
    //create if statement to not activate button if editText is empty
    if(!textCheck || !checkIfLetters) {
        return;
    }

    //will create variable 'mainButton' from the id of 'button' on MainActivity
    Button mainButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    //sets the 'mainButton' to respond to a click
    mainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //states that when 'mainButton' is clicked, it begins Intent to switch to Main2Activity
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

This is the method where the button should take me to the next activity. I save 'checkEditText' method and 'checkTextLetters' to boolean variables and pass them on as the parameters for this method so that if they equal `true` then the code will let the button take it to the next activity and if either are `false` then it won't do anything:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText editTextLines = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    //call method to use 'button' to go to next activity given all conditions are true
    boolean checkNotEmpty = checkEditText(editTextLines);
    boolean checkIfLetters = checkTextLetters(editTextLines);
    configureNextButton(checkNotEmpty,checkIfLetters);
}
```

Here is the main method where I put it all together and run it. It will work when I just set the `checkNotEmpty` and `checkIfLetters` to either `true` or `false`. Whenever I try and declare their value by calling my two methods then the button won't do anything.

**I changed the code and got rid of the 'checkEditText' and 'CheckTextLetters' methods in place of a TextWatcher method in the main method. It works but has bugs. 1. When it first runs, I can press the button and it goes to the next activity. 2. I can enter any letter and nums but won't accept just nums. I want the EditText to simply, not work if it is empty, allow only letters and spaces**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setClickable(false);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().length() == 0)
                button.setClickable(false);
            else{
                String line = s.toString();
                boolean value = line.matches("[a-zA-Z]");
                // set bool 'value' to check for alphabet letters
                if(value)
                    button.setClickable(true);
            }


        }
    });

    //call method to use 'button' to go to next activity given all conditions are true
    configureNextButton();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher).

See this example code: Implement this with your logic and change existing function to accept String instead of EditText.

```
    btnSubmit.setClickable(false);

    edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().length() == 0){
                btnSubmit.setClickable(false);
            }
            else
            {
                //Validate if its Alphabets only - if returned true,
                boolean value = validateAlphabetsOnly(s.toString());
                if(value)
                {
                    btnSubmit.setClickable(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

In `onCreate`, activity is just created. User hasn't got any chance to write in EditText yet. So you will need to use `TextChangedListener` for EditText.

Comment: The textWatcher part makes sense to me, but where am I supposed to implement this code? Should this be put inside of 'onCreate' and replace the 'checkEditText' and 'checkTextLetters' methods?

Comment: yes, in onCreate after initializations of button and edittext. And the method checkEditText is not needed anymore. Keep checkTextLetters outside onCreate so you can call it from TextWatcher. @Zachphilipp